# backbone marionette compositeview doesn't render properly after collection sort

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

Here's my JS code

```
var mainApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

mainApp.addRegions({        
        mainRegion: "#main-region"
});

var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var UserView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'user-item',
    template: '#user-item-tpl'
});

var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel,
    sortKey: 'id',
    comparator: function(item1, item2){
        item1 = item1.get(this.sortKey);
        item2 = item2.get(this.sortKey);
        return item1 > item2 ? 1 : (item1 < item2 ? -1 : 0);
    },
    sortByID: function(){
        this.sort();
    }
});

var UserListView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    className: 'user-view',
    tagName: 'div',
    itemView: UserView,
    itemViewContainer: '.user-list',
    events: {
        'click .btn' : 'doSort'
    },
    collection: new UserCollection([
        {id: 3, name: 'Peter'},
        {id: 1, name: 'Tom'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Mary'}
    ]),
    initialize: function(){

    },
    onShow: function(){

    },
    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
        $(this.itemViewContainer).append(itemView.el);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.template = _.template($('#user-view-tpl').html());
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    doSort: function(){
        this.collection.sortByID();
        this.collection.trigger('reset');
        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    }
});

mainApp.mainRegion.show(new UserListView());
```

Here's the html

```
<div id="main-region"></div>

<script id="user-view-tpl" type="text/template">
    <div class="user-list"></div>
    <a class="btn">SORT</a>
</script>

<script id="user-item-tpl" type="text/template">
    <%= id %> | <%= name %>
</script>
```

Whenever I trigger the doSort() function by click the "SORT" button, I can see the collection is sorted properly, but the compositeview doesn't react with "rest" and keeps showing to wrong order.

How can make the compositeview react automatically with the sort()?

PS: I think my code looks good, but it can run on jsfiddle, can give me some guidelines. Thanks.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chitocheng/fad8U/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a working example of your modified code : http://jsfiddle.net/AUZrY/1/

There were a few issues with your original code:

- your composite view didn't have a template (I changed it to a collection view)
- since you didn't have a template, there is nowhere for your `appendHtml` to attach child views
- you don't need to render views yourself with Marionette, especially replacing their html
- you had several models with the same id

Comment: Thanks David. But, I need the sort function to be trigger a button/link click. And I have no hints where you have called the sort function in your script. Please advice.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle. You had a comparator, which means the collection sorted itself automatically. In the code I wrote, the comparator is set only when you click the link. This is not production-quality code, and only serves to show you how sorting works.